# Goku's death counter?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

Technically Goku did die in the fight with hit. But because he was revived by means other than the dragon balls. Does this mean he didn't actually die?

Comment: Goku said he saw King Yemma for a second, that means he's already dead for a few moment until the ki blast shock him up.

Comment: Whether he was revived by Dragon Balls, a defibrillator or by any other means doesn't change the face that, even for a moment, he died

Comment: I had another question regarded that scene actually..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm only going to count the "main" series so gt will not be included.

So there was the start of dragon ball z, in the fight against Raditz,

He did not die against Freeza as he was said to have survived it.

He died when he teleported Cell to King Kais planet as he was exploding.

And lastly in the lasted episode as of now (72) of dragon ball super, it is said that when goku was struck by Hit, he saw King Yemma at the checkout station for a second before being brung back to life by the ki blast he had shot in the air.

So in conclusion Goku died 3 times if you count the last one which could be argued as debatable, otherwise his death count is 2.